How can we improve the question about HSK material?
The question https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/1400/43 is asking for good books about HSK exams.
As is, the question is likely to get closed as not constructive. But if the users show interest in improving it, I can leave it open and probably make it CW because it could be useful.
Please, keep in mind that if not enough interest is shown or if the question is not improved, I'll be forced to close it. Thanks for your attention. 

I don't know how to best handle that so that it fits within CLU's criteria. I searched online for good books but couldn't find anything (or only old threads that are no longer relevant). I think CLU is the best place for this kind of questions so it's a pity if they cannot be asked. I don't mind improving the question, but how?

I asked here to see if people wee interested... For example, we could wide the question and include all HSK levels? Just a thought.

To begin with, what is "HSK?"

@TomAu It's a test, like the JLPT, but for Chinese: Hanyu Shuiping Kaoshi

Thanks for giving a chance to the question anyway. However, surely there's something that might benefit everyone here right? Many people want to pass HSK and want to know how to best study it. How do we fit these kind of questions within CLU? Is it really off-topic? I know we have a big list of resources but that doesn't work because one cannot just wait and hope someone will add an answer for a question that hasn't (or couldn't) been asked. Perhaps, as you suggested, a wiki-like question for all the HSK levels?

@戴洛弘 I'll prepare an answer about that.

@Alenanno, I think we both agree that we need something about HSK on CLU, so that would be great if we could agree on a specific question. What do you think about a question that is about all the new HSK levels? i.e. something like "Good non-mock exam books to study HSK?" (mock exam books are so easy to find that it doesn't matter. What would be useful is some book to study the general grammatical points, vocabulary, etc.) I think that kind of question would better fit CLU's criteria, what do you think?

Update: The question was deleted due to inactivity.

The question has been closed as Not constructive, since it basically asks for something not definite (there is not a single objective answer) and also because it solicits discussions.
Note that this doesn't mean the question is lost forever. It can still be improved. Even deleted questions are not lost forever, because users with the Moderation Tools, can still see them, improve them, and flag for reopening. So for anyone who reads this: if a question is closed (and also if it's yours), don't panic!
You can still edit it. There's the edit button there, after all. It should make you think. :) 
Not all questions that deserve to be closed are bad questions. They are just badly-worded, maybe. It has happened in the past that I have down-voted open questions or, that I liked closed questions. This is why down-votes and closing are not the same thing.
We could make it Community Wiki, but we cannot use this tool so lightly. This would encourage people to think that "hey, I'll ask my question. If it's a list one, no worries, I'll get it CW". No, it doesn't work like this. I think this question has potential, but the community must participate, too.
I'd fix it myself, but I don't know how. I'm open for suggestions. There are many ways to ask for a good answer but still manage to get your "suggestion". All you need to accomplish is:

make it so that the question asks for something as scoped as possible (i.e. only a small handful of answers are possible, at maximum);
the question is still directed to your problem.

If you manage to fix it and still keep these two things in mind, I'll be glad to reopen it. By the way, if you need further suggestions, check this blog post about Good subjective, bad subjective questions. Those 6 guidelines are very useful. :)

Hmm... this question actually was very scoped because I was asking HSK books that were not lists of exam questions. If you check HSK books in a library, nearly all of them (well all of them in my case) will be like that. Someone commented in the question that "There currently aren't any books like this on the market" (according to him). So it wasn't a question out of the wild like "give me a book to read pinyin" but something quite specific. I hope you can reconsider reopening this question. I can add more details to it if needed, just let me know what.

What I meant is that, how many books are there for HSK? A user said "none", but there must be out there. And if there are, there are more than one... No?

Obviously there are many. It seems to be a really booming business. When I search for HSK on the Chinese Amazon I have 369 hits and when I search van 新HSK I have 112 hits. See http://www.amazon.cn/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?__mk_zh_CN=%E4%BA%9A%E9%A9%AC%E9%80%8A%E7%BD%91%E7%AB%99&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=HSK&x=0&y=0 and http://www.amazon.cn/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?__mk_zh_CN=%E4%BA%9A%E9%A9%AC%E9%80%8A%E7%BD%91%E7%AB%99&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=HSK&x=0&y=0#/ref=nb_sb_noss?__mk_zh_CN=%E4%BA%9A%E9%A9%AC%E9%80%8A%E7%BD%91%E7%AB%99&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=%E6%96%B0HSK

@Alenanno, I see your point, we cannot have subjective questions. But let's be honest, you're the only one judging whether a question is subjective or not because there's so few people here - so what if you're wrong (what if you're being subjective ;).
For example, I search for "book" on the German SE and I find lots of interesting questions about people asking for books etc., stuff that would be closed here. Since there's more people on the German SE, perhaps we could at least consider whether they are doing something right over there?
So my question is: my question was not a good one. Ok, I don't mind. The bigger topic is - how can we make it right? Let me hope that a HSK-related question is a good one a Chinese language SE. Since you have some experience on other language SE, I hope you can make some suggestions. (Sorry to address you directly - I don't like discussions to get personal on Meta - but since you're the only one who reads most post here... ;)

This is not the first time I come across a situation like this one. If you want we can ask some opinions from someone "upper" than me. SE sites are not only for beginners but also for experts. If we allow too many questions like this, we'll drive experts away and with 98 visits/day, I don't think it's convenient for us. I said it and I'll repeat it: fix your question, ask for help on chat, from other mods, SE team, anyone. But let's avoid the CW card as much as possible. And by the way, it's not true your question is not good, it is good. It's just badly worded. :)
